# Regd: Log assertion markers

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim

How to make inverted triangle markers visible in Questsim environment. I am using wild card operator for logging waveform (.wlf). The markers are used for debugging assertion based verification.

Comment: Your question is poorly worded and you should tell how you use the tool. e.g. On Windows 7 from the gui, or On RHEL from the command line.

Comment: I am using Questa from GUI in a linux based environment. Whenever there is an error in DUT, I wanted to see the place where the error has occurred through an assertion marker in waveform viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Questasim with the option `-assertdebug`.

Please search for assertdebug in the [questasim manual](http://rise.cse.iitm.ac.in/people/faculty/kama/prof/questa_sim_user_manual.pdf) for more information.